# Conditions of $N \triangleleft G$ such that the quotient $G/N$ has trivial centre

Tags: finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group whose centre is trivial and let $N$ be its normal subgroup. What does $N$ need to satisfy such that the quotient $G/N$ has a trivial centre?

References to any literature would be highly appreciated.

Comment: If you're looking for a condition that just depends on $N$, isn't it just that all automorphisms of $N$ are inner?

Comment: I'm aware that if $Z(G/N)$ is trivial, then the subgroup $K$ satisfying $[G,K]=N$ must be equal to $N$. The question is how does that relate to the fact that $\mathrm{Aut}(N) = \mathrm{Inn}(N)$? For example, let $G=S_4$ and $N= \langle (1 \, 2)(3 \, 4), (2 \, 3)(1 \, 4) \rangle$. Clearly $Z(G/N) = Z(S_3) = 1$ but $\mathrm{Aut}(N) \neq 1 = \mathrm{Inn}(N)$.